# Running command-line tools giving python3 bad interpreter, no such file or directory error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, python

I have two versions of python installed on a server: `/usr/local/bin/python3` (version 3.6.3) `/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/bin/python` (version 2.7.15)

Earlier today I removed python version 3.6.3 and 3.4.0 and 3.7.0  using `sudo rm -r` (My MISTAKE!!) that was under `/usr/bin/python`. I thought this would be fine since I had `/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/bin/python` (version 2.7.15).

I'm running a few command-line tools that are written in python and they generate the error: -`bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Yet, if I just execute `python` python seems to be working.

Not sure what's causing this error? Additionally `pip3` is also causing the same `-bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory error`.

Update:
I removed python3 because this was something I installed myself anyway.
You're going to laugh but this is Ubuntu 14.04.1. Not by choice! Someone else set up this shared server before I came along, and no one ever updated.

Comment: What do `which python3` and which `python` say?

Comment: I removed python3 because when I installed it I got some errors, maybe not my brightest idea. `which python` gives `/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/bin/python`

Comment: If you removed Python 3, it is not surprising that you get `/usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter`.   `pip3` is for Python version 3; there might be a `pip2`, `pip2.7` somewhere. On the other hand, it may also be just `pip`. Try `pip --version` to be sure. Forced re-install of Python3 may also remove much of your problems.